# How loading scripts affect window.load event? Since scripts can further load new scripts, at which point window.load stops?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser

I know that we can use `defer` `async` and no attribute which results in different ways of loading a script. But I want to know how does `window.load` event fit into the picture?

I noticed that it waits for the async scrips too. But since scripts can dynamically load new scripts, how window.load event decides when to stop?

Answer (score 0):

"[The end](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#the-end)" section of [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/) is what you're looking for I guess.